# is there a spring property to set transaction mode to aspectJ

Tags: spring-boot, transactions, aspectj

I need transactions for private methods and self referenced method (in a spring boot 2.7.5 application).  for this documentation suggest "mode=aspectj"

`Consider the use of AspectJ (see below) if you need to annotate non-public methods.`

My problem all documentation about it seems to rely on xml files.

Is there a property to set this mode?
Are there other things besides needed to get `@Transactional` working on private methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a Spring user, rather generally interested in AOP topics, but I think you might want to use

```java
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
```

For reference, please read the [`EnableTransactionManagement` javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/6.0.6/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html).

Of course, you also need the `spring-aspects` dependency and, depending on whether you want to use compile-time or load-time weaving, either AspectJ Maven plugin (or the equivalent for your favourite build tool) or `-javaagent:/path/to/aspectjweaver-<version>.jar` on the JVM command line.

Comment: Sorry, I just realised that you asked for a property, not an annotation. I just focused on your wish to avoid XML configuration. I figured that you need annotations in your code anyway, so you could also use annotation-based config. Maybe there is a config property I am unaware of, but I did not find any, at least for [Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html). As for Spring Core or Spring TX specifically, I do not know either.